# minikube mount broken on VPN

Tags: kubernetes, vpn, minikube

So I'm having issues with minikube mount command while on Big-IP VPN. Basically, the command looks like it's able to ssh into the minikube VM, but for whatever reason, minikube can't mount the host folder.

```
$ minikube mount --v=10 app_shared_sec:/app/shared/sec
Mounting app_shared_sec into /app/shared/sec on the minikube VM
This daemon process needs to stay alive for the mount to still be accessible...
ufs starting
Using SSH client type: native
&{{{<nil> 0 [] [] []} docker [0x140f940] 0x140f910  [] 0s} 127.0.0.1 57930 <nil> <nil>}
About to run SSH command:
sudo umount /app/shared/sec;
SSH cmd err, output: Process exited with status 32: umount: /app/shared/sec: not mounted.

Using SSH client type: native
&{{{<nil> 0 [] [] []} docker [0x140f940] 0x140f910  [] 0s} 127.0.0.1 57930 <nil> <nil>}
About to run SSH command:

sudo mkdir -p /app/shared/sec || true;
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=tcp,port=51501,dfltuid=1001,dfltgid=1001,version=9p2000.u,msize=262144 192.168.99.1 /app/shared/sec;
sudo chmod 775 /app/shared/sec || true;
SSH cmd err, output: <nil>: mount: /app/shared/sec: mount(2) system call failed: Connection timed out.
```

Running `netstat` within the minikube VM seems to point to it being able to read the host.

```
$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.99.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

The issue appears to be because VPN blows away the vboxnet interface on the host, minikube VM has no way of communicating with it, causing the mount to fail. When trying to re-create the route, Big-IP seems to watch for changes and removes it. Not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: where are you running minikube MacOS? Linux? Windows?

Comment: @Rico I'm running MacOS